# Complex MySQL SORT based on time

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, select, mysqli

I have to sort MySQL records based on a unix time field. However, some records hold a value of 1 instead of time. Here's how I want them sorted, assuming current time is 125:

```
127
130
132
133
1
1
1
1
124
122
119
```

As you can see, the top section is records in ASC order by the time field with the soonest time first, these are followed by all the records that are marked with 1 instead of a proper time, and then the records from the past in DESC order. Is this doable?

Comment: maybe with two separate queries, considering that the order changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following code:

```
drop table if exists numbers;
create table numbers ( value int );
insert into numbers values 
(119),(122),(124),(127),(130),(131),(1),(1),(1),(1);

select 
    value 
from numbers
order by if( value = 1, 125, if( value > 125, 99999 - value, value ) )  desc
```

which produces:

```
value
-----
127
130
131
1
1
1
1
124
122
119
```

Jus replace all occurrences of `125` with the current time and `99999' with the largest time value that you might encounter in your table.

Comment: So for the largest value I could do MAX?

Comment: MAX() didn't work, but I added a big number (3000000000) and subtracted value from that and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about one mysql query but i have tried something with php and mysql both so try this hope it can help you

Assuming table name as test and field name as date and time as 125

```
    $get_latest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE time > 125 ORDER BY time ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_latest))
{
    $result[] = $row['time'];
}
$get_remaining = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE time <= 125 ORDER BY time ASC");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_remaining))
{
    $result[] = $row1['time'];
}

foreach($result as $r)
{
    echo $r.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had it almost working with MySQL ORDER BY so I knew it could be done without PHP. See the other answer above. Thanks for your help though.